# How to turn a vertical bar into start/end of \verb?

Tags: verbatim

Somehow, `ltxdoc` document class is doing this. I'm trying to reproduce this:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```

Renders as:

[image]

How can I do the same without `ltxdoc`? I want `|abc|` to turn into `\verb{abc}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

(updated after egreg's comment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{shortvrb} % far less code than doc
\AtBeginDocument{\MakeShortVerb{\|}}


\begin{document}
    Hello, |world|!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\usepackage{shortvrb}`?